# How to import users (openvpn) into PFsense

Tags: openvpn, pfsense

I have a OpenVPN setup from an barebone server with ~60 users, and searching for a way to import those users with certificates into a new PFsense setup.
They don't have passwords, because we use ldap as authentication for openvpn.

It would be nice with an API or something which can be done from the shell.

I would like to avoid changing directly in the config.xml if that is possible.

Answer (score 1):

I am unable to understand why do you wanna import clients certificates to pfsense. IMHO it's not necessary because server do not need it to successful authentication/authorization of the client. Everything you need to do is to import CA certificate, gateway certificate, it's private key and configuration of OpenVPN server.